# Appending a ADT list seg fault

Tags: c, list, segmentation-fault

So im trying to append a list but every time I use the append function, it just crashes (SEG FAULT). I narrowed it down to around a line that in insert value and I marked it in the code below.

so here is the structs/lists

```
/*Declration of the struct*/
typedef struct Element {
    value_type value;
    Key_type key;
    struct Element * next;
    struct Element * sort;
}Node;

/*ADT declration*/
typedef struct List {
    Node * head;
    Node * head_sort;
    Node * tail;
    Node * tail_sort;
    int size;
}Sorted_List;
```

Here is the rest of the code

```
/*Fucntion to add values ot the end using tail*/
int append_list (Sorted_List * List, value_type value, Key_type key){
    int result = insert_value(List->tail, value, key) != NULL;
    if ( result == SUCCESS){
        List->size++;
        List->tail = List->tail->sort;

    }

    return result;
}

int append (Sorted_List * List, value_type value, Key_type key){
    return is_empty(List) ? push(List, value, key)
    : append_list(List, value, key);
}

/*Function to insert value into list*/
Node * insert_value (Node * node, value_type value, Key_type key){

    /*Setting a new node and mallocing it */
    Node * new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    /*Checking for the new node to not equal null*/
    if (new_node != NULL){

        /*Setting the values for it*/
        new_node->value = value;
        new_node->key = key;

        /*Setting the new node next to equal old nodes next*/
        new_node->sort = node->sort;

        /*Setting old node next to equal new node*/
        node->sort = new_node;
/////I receive the error around this line^^^^/////

    }

    return new_node;
}
```

EDIT::
so here is the code for the push function used in the program
add front's job is to add the values rot the front
and find_prev_gt's job is to find the previes largest valus's location to add the new number

```
/*Function to push a value to to the front of the list*/
int push (Sorted_List * List, value_type value, Key_type key) {
    Node * node = NULL;
    int empty = 0;
    empty = is_empty(List);



Node * next_node = NULL;
    Node * insert_node = find_prev_gt(List->head, key);
    int result = FAILURE;
    if (insert_node == NULL) {
        add_front(&(List->head), value,key);

    }
    else {
        next_node = insert_node->sort;
        if (next_node == NULL || next_node->key != key)
            insert_value(insert_node, value,key);

    }
    result = (node != NULL );
    /*Returns success if reseult is succesfull*/
       if ( result == SUCCESS) {
           List->size++;
          if (empty)
              List->tail = List->head;
       }
    return result;
}


Node * add_front(Node ** head, value_type value, Key_type key){
    Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (new_node != NULL) {
        new_node->key = key;
        new_node->value = value;
        new_node->sort = *head;
        *head = new_node;  }
    return new_node;

}

/*Function to check if list is empty*/
int is_empty (Sorted_List * list){
    return list->head == NULL;
}

Node * find_prev_gt ( Node * head, Key_type key ) {
    Node * node = head, * prev = NULL;
    while (node != NULL && node->key < key){
        prev = node;
        node = node->sort;

    }
    return prev;

}
```

Comment: @Mohamed ElMoursi The list definition does not make sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yeah so the definitions were given to us and I can't change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> every time I use the append function, it just crashes

Your problem is in the function *push* where the value of *node* does not change after its initialization to NULL, so in

> ```
>   if ( result == SUCCESS) {
>       List->size++;
>      if (empty)
>          List->tail = List->head;
>   }
> ```

the test is always false and the associated code is not executed

You just need to change two lines, replace the line

> ```
> add_front(&(List->head), value,key);
> ```

by

```
 node = add_front(&(List->head), value,key);
```

and the line

> ```
> insert_value(insert_node, value,key);
> ```

by

```
 node = insert_value(insert_node, value,key);
```

If I do these two changes and I prefix your code by the definitions

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int value_type;
typedef int Key_type;

#define SUCCESS 1
#define FAILURE 0
```

and add the following *main* :

```
int main()
{
  Sorted_List list = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
  Node * node;

  append(&list, 2, 22);
  append(&list, 3, 33);
  append(&list, 1, 11);

  for (node = list.head; node != NULL; node = node->sort)
    printf("[key=%d, value=%d] ", node->key, node->value);
  putchar('\n');

  return 0;
}
```

the execution writes :

```
[key=22, value=2] [key=33, value=3] [key=11, value=1]
```

Out of that in *Sorted_List* your code change *head* and *tail* but not *head_sort* nor *tail_sort* but in *Node* you set *sort* but not *next*, this is not logical, furthermore the nodes are not sorted

Comment: thank you too much for your help, it worked perfectly. and for the tail_sort and head_sort. I just revised it, and im using them now. And changed the code to work with next. Anyways thank you for your help

Comment: @MohamedElMoursi you welcome, you see I really needed the definition (code) of *push* ;-) Happy coding